Is there an alternative way to access the Google Picker API in an electron App while still using the file:// protocol?
I am trying to create an integration with Google Drive. Now the authentication with google drive seems to be working fine. The struggle came upon the integration with the Google Picker API. I am trying to display the Google Drive "modal", however, I kept running this error: [Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://docs.google.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'". After doing some research on the matter, it seemed like the problem was caused due to electron's file protocol that loads the file.
I could be very naive or inexperienced, however, it seems like the only alternative is to now load the client via URL not File. I have tried changing the rules for CSP, and more but nothing seemed to do the trick. I don't really want to change the way I load the file because the App is quite big, and I am short on time.
Is there another alternative to the above at all?
I am thinking of just listing the files from the drive api and then creating a custom electron modal to display them, but I am still hoping that someone has a better solution to my problem. Any help would be immensely appreciated.
